# Making manually mounted LUKS volume visible in Nautilus

Tags: mount, arch-linux, gnome3, nautilus, luks

In Unity under Ubuntu, when I mounted a volume under `/media`, then it was shown in Nautilus, as if it was mounted by gvfs.

Now I'm running GNOME 3.20.1, which mounts its drives under `/run/media/[user]`. When I mounted my LUKS volume using `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab` under `/mnt`, it disappeared from "Other locations" submenu in Nautilus. Even, when I mounted it under `/run/media/[user]`, it still stayed that way.

How to replicate the pre-udisks2 behavior of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that adding `x-gvfs-show` to the mount options does the job.